# Elements of countable set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Set $S$ consisting of all Cauchy sequences $(a_i)$  with $a_i \in \Bbb N,   \forall i$.

Is this set S is countable? 
How to check countable set having cauchy sequences?

Comment: What's your progress so far? Did you think about what a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb N$ looks like?

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a sequence is a Cauchy sequence if for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N\in\mathbb N$ so that for any $m,n>N$, $\left|a_m-a_n\right|<\epsilon$. Now choose $\epsilon<1$. Given that your sequences consist only of natural numbers, what does this imply for $a_m-a_n$?

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to all the finite subsets of N. Number of finite subsets of N is countable because  every subset is a subset of (1,2,...,n) and number of subsets of this is $2^n$ for any n. Countable union of countable sets is countable. Every sequence is eventually constant....so do the same.

Comment: A sequence of natural numbers can be "Cauchy" only if it is "eventually constant.  That is, there exist some integer, N, such that, if m and n are both larger than N, then $a_m= a_n$.  Every such sequence can be identified with that constant.